# How to trim input audio in FFMPEG?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

I want to concat come audio files with specific silence between them. Then, I need to trim the input audio to make the in-between space accurate.

I tried

```
ffmpeg \
-i 1.mp3 -af silenceremove=1:0:-50dB \
-f lavfi -t 0.5 -i anullsrc \
-i 2.mp3 -af silenceremove=1:0:-50dB \
-f lavfi -t 0.5 -i anullsrc -i 3.mp3 \
-af silenceremove=1:0:-50dB \
-filter_complex 'concat=n=5:v=0:a=1' out.mp3
```

but received an error:

> Option af (set audio filters) cannot be applied to input url anullsrc
>   -- you are trying to apply an input option to an output file or vice versa.
>
> Move this option before the file it belongs to.
>
> Error parsing options for input file anullsrc.
>
> Error opening input files: Invalid argument

It seems `-af` is applied to the next `-f` option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filters are not source operations, but are carried out on streams selected for output.

In this case, since you have multiple files which will be joined, carry out all filtering within the graph.

```
ffmpeg \
-f lavfi -t 0.5 -i anullsrc \
-i 1.mp3 \
-i 2.mp3 \
-i 3.mp3 \
-filter_complex '[1]silenceremove=1:0:-50dB[a1];\
                 [2]silenceremove=1:0:-50dB[a2];\
                 [3]silenceremove=1:0:-50dB[a3];\
                 [a1][0][a2][0][a3]concat=n=5:v=0:a=1' out.mp3
```